# Is (+∞)(−∞) undefined? Why?

Tags: measure-theory, infinity

I happened to get a glimpse of an exercise and a claim in it soon beset me:

[image]

I have no problem about the exercise itself. What puzzled me is that I cannot find any justification for the claim that $(+\infty)(-\infty)$ is undefined. What's wrong with just defining the product to be $-\infty$? Is it a typo of the text, or did I miss anything in understanding the undefinedness of this product? I hope someone can please help me clarify it. Thank you. PS: this exercise follows a section discussing measure theory. PS2: by "$\mathcal{E}$-measurable", it means the co-domain is $\bar R$.

Comment: You are right. $(\infty)(-\infty)$ is not indeterminate.

Comment: The question seems open... See e.g. Satish Shirali & Harkrishan Lal Vasudeva [Measure and Integration (2019, Springer)](https://books.google.it/books?id=HkewDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6), page 6.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA the source you link shows it's not open and user5280911 and Kavi Rama Murthy are right.

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number, but apart from this, Masacroso's comment contains a sign error.

Comment: In what is usually meant with "$0\cdot \infty$", we do not have $0\cdot \infty=0$ in general. The limit can be anything.

Comment: I'm also quite amazed to see the assertion that $0 \cdot \infty = 0$ is defined.

Comment: @Mark: the text has "The reader is cautioned that there is no unanimity among authors about the
properties (a)–(i). [11] includes our (g) but [12] specifically excludes all parts of it except for ∞∞ = ∞."

Comment: @LeeMosher That's standard in integration theory. You want the integral of $x \mapsto 0$ be zero, even if the domain of integration has infinite measure. And you want the integral of any measurable function over a null set be zero, even if the function is infinite on that set. Thus one defines $0 \cdot \infty = 0$. (See e.g. section 1.22 in Rudin's RCA)

Comment: @Lee this horrible "convention" of setting $0\cdot \infty =0$ is common in bad texts of integration and measure theory. A carefully exposition of Lebesgue or Bochner integration theory doesn't need it, as is easy to check in the literature

Comment: @Masacroso $0\cdot \infty =0$ is standard in many fields just like $0^0=1$, $1^\infty=1$ and $0/0=0$.

Comment: Of course, $(-\infty)(+\infty)$ is not indeterminate.  But whether it is "defined" is up to the one giving the definitions.  I assume that text (whatever it is) specified what operations are "defined" for the purposes of that text.  Can you prove Exercise 2.29 if you arbitrarily define $(-\infty)(+\infty) = -\infty$?  Similarly, can you prove Exercise 2.29 if you arbitrariy define $0/0 = 17$?

Comment: @GEdgar: It is an intriguing idea to base the (un)definedness on the application context (i.e., "purposes"). Unfortunately, the text does not specify any definition of operations, perhaps because the discussion of measure theory is only a small part of the text. The good news is that it means the text provides rich application context for me to ponder why $(+\infty)(-\infty)$ is regarded as undefined under specific appli. If we define arbitrarily $(+\infty)(-\infty)=-\infty$, I can prove $f\cdot g$ is measurable by discussing by cases. Similarly, I can prove under arbitrary definition of 0/0.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Do you happen to know the standard of $(+\infty)(-\infty)$ in measure and integration theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the principle behind the notion of  "(un)determined" operations involving $0$ and $\pm \infty $.

Let
$$
  \overline{\mathbb R} = \mathbb R ∪ \{+\infty ,  -\infty \},
  $$
and  let $\odot$ be any mathematical operation such as sum, difference,
product, division or exponentiation.  Given  $\alpha $ and $\beta $ in  $\overline{\mathbb R}$,
the question I want to address here is what does it mean to  say that $\alpha \odot\beta $ is (un)determined.

For the sake of argument  suppose that $\{x_n\}_n$ and $\{y_n\}_n$ are sequences of real numbers  such  that
$$
  \lim_{n\to \infty } x_n=\alpha , \quad  \text{and} \quad \lim_{n\to \infty } y_n=\beta .
  $$

One may then ask what is the value of
$
  \displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty } x_n\odot y_n
  $?

It is often the case that the answer to this question cannot be found  based only on the information given!  For
example, if $x_n=1/n$, $x'_n=2/n$, and  $y_n=n$, then
$$
  \lim_{n\to \infty } x_n=0=\lim_{n\to \infty } x'_n, \quad  \text{while} \quad \lim_{n\to \infty } y_n=\infty .
  $$
However
$$
  \lim_{n\to \infty } x_ny_n = 1 \neq  2 = \lim_{n\to \infty } x_n'y_n.
  $$

Does this say  that $0\cdot \infty =1$, or would it be $2$?  Well, I guess
this says that $0\cdot \infty $ is undetermined!

Based on this, one may give the following formal definition:

**Definition**.  If $\alpha,\beta \in \overline{\mathbb R}$, and if $\odot$ is any mathematical operation, we say that
$\alpha \odot\beta $ is *determined*, and that its value is $\gamma $, if for every  sequences $\{x_n\}_n$ and $\{y_n\}_n$ (of standard real numbers) such that
$$
  \lim_{n\to \infty } x_n=\alpha , \quad  \text{and} \quad \lim_{n\to \infty } y_n=\beta ,
  $$
one has that   $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty } x_n\odot y_n=\gamma $.  Otherwise we say that $\alpha \odot\beta $ is *undetermined*.

According to this, it is clear that $(+\infty )\cdot (-\infty )=-\infty $, and that $0\cdot \infty $ is undetermined.

Nevertheless, there are certain
areas of Math in which it might be sensible to adopt
special  conventions.

In Integration Theory, as mentioned by @DanielFischer,  it is sensible to define $0\cdot \infty =0$, because the integral of the
zero function over an infinite measure space is equal to zero.   Another example is Algebra, where the definition of  a polynomial as
$$
  p(x) = \sum_{n=0}^d a_nx^n,
  $$
only makes sense if one adopts the convention that  $x^0=1$, the case $x=0$ included!

---

PS: I am well aware that the level of my answer is not quite on par with the question.  But it turns out that the present
answer, which is certainly what the 'experts' have in mind, is not too often spelled out and perhaps Math  begginers might
benefit from it!

Comment: You mean $\cdots$ even if $x=0$ and not $x=0!=1!$

Comment: How do you like it now :-) ?

Comment: Like it!  Thank you.  I just thought it was funny.  When I first read it, it looked like you were somehow comparing eponentiation with factorial!

Comment: Also, I like the explanation, not just the last sentence.

Comment: @Ruy: Thanks for the detailed exposition. I'm sure both math beginners or people from other disciplines will benefit from it. May I ask you a quick question: do you happen to know what is the commonly accepted idea on the (un)definedness of $(+\infty)(-\infty)$ among 'experts' of Measure and Integral Theory? Is this product commonly regarded to be defined as $-\infty$ among 'experts' of Measure and Integral Theory and hence the claim in the exercise is only the author's personal convention, or there is no commonly accepted resolution at all on the (un)definedness of this product ...

Comment: ... among 'experts' of Measure and Integral Theory? Thanks.

Comment: @user5280911, My feeling is that most 'experts' would agree that $(-\infty)(\infty)=-\infty$ and that the book you quoted is an exception to that rule.  However, when it comes to choice of convention, Math is no longer an exact discipline.  It is enough to say that  there is no agreement regarding  the most basic set of Mathematics, namely the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$, with some people proposing that 0 belongs to $\mathbb N$ and some not!

Comment: @user5280911 the identity $(-\infty)\cdot \infty=-\infty$ is part of the definition of [the extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line)